# Pictures do not display by MATH.RANDOM

Tags: reactjs, image, dom, random, jsx

We have images in folders, named (face1.png,...,face6.png)
using this code; I can't display images, we randomly retrieve photos:

```
import React from "react";
import jeuxde from "../images/jeuxde.jpg";


export default class JeuDe extends React.Component{
    constructor (props){
        super(props);
        this.state= {face: null, compteur: 0, fin: false};
    };



jouer(){
    const valeur = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
    this.setState({
        face:this.state.face = valeur,
        compteur:this.state.compteur+=valeur,
    })
    const image = document.getElementById("des")
    image.src = '../images/face' +valeur + '.png'
}

initialiser (){
    this.setState({ 
        face: null, compteur: 0, fin: false
    });
}
render(){
    const styleImage={width:"100px",height:"100px"};
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={jeuxde} alt={"jeux de"}/>
            <h1>Jeu de Dé...</h1>
            <h2>face:{this.state.face}</h2>
            <div >
            <img id="des" style={styleImage} />

            </div>
            <h2>nombre d'essais {this.state.compteur}</h2>
            <button onClick={(()=>this.jouer())}>jouer</button>
            
            <p>Bravo vous avez trouvez la face cachée...</p>
            <button onClick={(()=>this.initialiser())}>Initialiser</button>
        </div>
        );

    }
}
```

The problem:

I'm using this code but images don't display in the DOM,

```
const image = document.getElementById("des")
image.src = '../images/face' +valeur + '.png'
```

but when I use inspect, I find the pictures change in the src but not display in DOM. When I use it I get

`<img id="des" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="../images/face3.png">`

This `src="../images/face3.png"`is added when the button `<button onClick={(()=>this.jouer())}>jouer</button>` is clicked randomly but images don't display in the DOM

[image: i need image display in dom*]

Answer (score 0):

i would use the img src to give it the image path instead of using the document.getElementById

```js
import React from "react";
import jeuxde from "../images/jeuxde.jpg";

export default class JeuDe extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { face: null, compteur: 0, fin: false, image:''};
  }

  jouer() {
    const valeur = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    this.setState({
      face: (this.state.face = valeur),
      compteur: (this.state.compteur += valeur),
      image: "../images/face" + valeur + ".png",
    });
  }

  initialiser() {
    this.setState({
      face: null,
      compteur: 0,
      fin: false,
      image: "",
    });
  }
  render() {
    const styleImage = { width: "100px", height: "100px" };
    return (
      <div>
        <img src={jeuxde} alt={"jeux de"} />
        <h1>Jeu de Dé...</h1>
        <h2>face:{this.state.face}</h2>
        <div>
          <img id="des" style={styleImage} src={this.state.image} />
        </div>
        <h2>nombre d'essais {this.state.compteur}</h2>
        <button onClick={() => this.jouer()}>jouer</button>

        <p>Bravo vous avez trouvez la face cachée...</p>
        <button onClick={() => this.initialiser()}>Initialiser</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: but images don't display

Comment: is the path correct?

Comment: yes, the path of the folder is "src\images"